# create dynamically checkbox in blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I´m traying to create list of checkbox in my blade with all roles that i have in my `DB`. I´m doing loop to get all roles and if to check that roles have this user that i´m doing edit:

```
@foreach($roles as $rol)
   @foreach ($selRoles as $role)
     @if ($role == $rol->id)
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <input type="checkbox" name="rol" checked=checked class="form-check-input" value="{{ $rol->id }}" id="{{ $rol->id }}">
          {{ $rol->name }}
       </div>
     @else
      <div class="col-md-4">
         <input type="checkbox" name="rol" class="form-check-input" value="{{ $rol->id }}" id="{{ $rol->id }}">
         {{ $rol->name }}
      </div>                                                   
     @endif
   @endforeach
@endforeach
```

With this code, my problem it´s that all my roles it´s duplicated. In my controller i have this:

```
public function edit(User $usuario)
    {
        $roles = Bouncer::role()->orderBy('title', 'DESC')->get();
        $selRoles = $usuario->roles->pluck('id')->toArray(); //selRoles it´s roles from user
    
        $usuario->load('roles');

        return view('admin.empleados.edit', compact('usuario', 'roles','selRoles'));
    }
```

and retult in blade it´s:

```
teleoperadora
teleoperadora
teleoperadora
repartidor
repartidor
repartidor
prueba
prueba
prueba
Jefe de equipo
Jefe de equipo
Jefe de equipo
jefa-sala
jefa-sala
jefa-sala
instalador
instalador
```

for example. I don´t know that i´m doing bad for get this result in my blade. Anybody can help me please?

Thanks for read and help. Sorry for my english

Comment: @AkshayGireesh  thanks for your response, but i don´t understand very well that you tell me

Answer (score 0):

Your roles get duplicated because you are using two `foreach` loops. Your selected roles are an array, so it should suffice to check if a role->id is in that array:

```
@foreach($roles as $role)
<div class="col-md-4">
  <input type="checkbox" name="rol" @if(in_array($role->id, $selRoles))checked=checked@endif class="form-check-input" value="{{ $role->id }}" id="{{ $role->id }}">
  {{ $role->name }}
</div>
@endforeach
```

The part `@if(in_array($role->id, $selRoles))checked=checked@endif` will check the checkbox if the role's id is in your array of selected roles.